# Alternatives to full Xcode install for simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I've been tasked with building a demo suite of our iOS application for our sales team to run on their laptops.

I know that I can install Xcode on their machines and then create a shortcut for the simulator, but that feels really heavyweight for our sales folks.

I've used my google foo and I see that there are several choices in the windows world, but I've not seen an alternative for OS X. Does anyone have suggestions for a standalone iOS emulator on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Install Xcode.app on your system
2. Build & Run your demo app, targeting each sim device you want them to demo (or use xcrun simctl install  /path/to/your/built.app)
3. Make a tarball of ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
4. Untar that tarball into ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices on each demo machine.
5. Install Xcode.app on each demo machine and just place Simulator.app in the Dock.

If you're really concerned about disk space, you can delete a bunch of things inside of Xcode.app that aren't needed, but make sure you keep CoreSimulator.framework, SimulatorKit.framework, Simulator.app, simctl, and anything that has "CoreSimulator" as a parent directory.

Comment: That's pretty much where I'm at right now. I was hoping there was a light weight way to achieve this result. Unfortunately it does not appear that there is. Thank you for the detailed response Jeremey.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://appetize.io/?

I've used a few demos in the browser and it seems like a very lightweight way to at least demo an app (although performance is suffers a little since its in a web browser).

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to work offline. So many sales demos are done in places with spotty, or no wifi.